# Could you tell me, what's wrong with my request mapping?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, maven-2

I'm trying to do request mapping for the home controller. My home controller has a method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/create", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView Create(Locale locale, Model model)
{
    return new ModelAndView("create");
}
```

And my view resolver is configured in the following way:

```
<!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the   /WEB-INF/views directory -->
<beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</beans:bean>
```

And there is a view in the folder: **views/create.jsp**

The hyperlink in the home controller is constructed with this code:

```
<p><a href = "/create">New topic</a></p>
```

But, when i'm clicking on the hyperlink,  i'm receiving an error #404.

Comment: have you configured the servlet mapping and request dispatcher

Comment: have you ever set a breakpoint in the controller method, to check if the problem is that the controller method is not found, or the view is not found?

Comment: Ralph, i have set a breakpoint, the controller is found. The problem is to find a source.

Comment: Is the JSP in /views/create.jsp, or in /WEB-INF/views/create.jsp?

Comment: JB Nizet, yes. JSP is located in \WEB-INF\views\create.jsp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have your server under the folder  `http://localhost/AppName/` and you are redirecting to index by using

```
<p><a href = "/create">New topic</a></p>
```

you will get to `http://localhost/create` instead of `http://localhost/AppName/create`.

Second:

I had the same problem, as you are describing here and it was solved, as soon as I mapped views with extensions.

So in my case:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/create.html", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView Create(Locale locale, Model model)
{
    return new ModelAndView("create");
}
```

and your dispatcher server should be:

```
 <servlet>
    <servlet-name>SomeServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>SomeServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

Maybe it will not help but just give it a try. I can't explain why has it happened, but it just solved my problem.

Comment: Thanks, the error with hyperlink is resolved. Now, i'm trying to make ViewResolver to work

Comment: Danny, it seems, that your first advice works. The AppName is **CASE SENSITIVE**. I see such a thing for the first time in the Web.